# Merge two map or collections in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have 2 maps in my input payload, which I have to merge based on the id and create 1 map as the output data mentioned below. How do I accomplish this in Groovy?

Input Data:

```
{'orders': "{"30452": {"id": "L0089", "program": "ll"},
             "30003": {"id": "a1421", "program": "cld"},
             "32818": {"id": "a1212", "program": "clm"},
             "81224": {"id": "A0D", "program": "ccc"},
             "40281": {"id": "88ds1", "program": "clm"},
             "44291": {"id": "37000", "program": "com"}
}

'tier': {"L0089": "1", "A0D": "3", "88ds1", "1", "37000", "2","a1421":"2", "a1212":"1"}
```

Output Data:

```
{'orders': "{"30452": {"id": "L0089", "program": "ll", "tier": "1"},
             "30003": {"id": "a1421", "program": "cld", "tier": "2"},
             "32818": {"id": "a1212", "program": "clm", "tier": "1"},
             "81224": {"id": "A0D", "program": "ccc", "tier":"3"},
             "40281": {"id": "88ds1", "program": "clm", "tier": "1"},
             "44291": {"id": "37000", "program": "com", "tier": "2"}}
```

Comment: Please post your code and the output you are getting so far so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be the following:

```
def orders = ["30452": ["id": "L0089", "program": "ll"],
              "30003": ["id": "a1421", "program": "cld"],
              "32818": ["id": "a1212", "program": "clm"],
              "81224": ["id": "A0D",   "program": "ccc"],
              "40281": ["id": "88ds1", "program": "clm"],
              "44291": ["id": "37000", "program": "com"]]

def tiers = ["L0089": "1", 
             "A0D":   "3", 
             "88ds1": "1", 
             "37000": "2",
             "a1421": "2", 
             "a1212": "1"]

orders = orders.collectEntries { orderId, data -> 
  if (tiers[data.id]) data.tier = tiers[data.id]
  [orderId, data]
}

println "orders after adding tiers"
println "orders: $orders"
```

which when run prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

orders after adding tiers
orders: [30452:[id:L0089, program:ll, tier:1], 30003:[id:a1421, program:cld, tier:2], 32818:[id:a1212, program:clm, tier:1], 81224:[id:A0D, program:ccc, tier:3], 40281:[id:88ds1, program:clm, tier:1], 44291:[id:37000, program:com, tier:2]]

─➤
```

**addendum using json after comments**

If your in-data is json, you can do something like this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def orderData = '''
{"orders":  {"30452": {"id": "L0089", "program": "ll"},
             "30003": {"id": "a1421", "program": "cld"},
             "32818": {"id": "a1212", "program": "clm"},
             "81224": {"id": "A0D",   "program": "ccc"},
             "40281": {"id": "88ds1", "program": "clm"},
             "44291": {"id": "37000", "program": "com"}
}'''

def tierData = '''{"tiers": {"L0089": "1", "A0D": "3", "88ds1": "1", "37000": "2","a1421": "2", "a1212": "1"}}'''

def parser = new JsonSlurper()

def orders = parser.parseText(orderData).orders
def tiers  = parser.parseText(tierData).tiers

orders = orders.collectEntries { orderId, data -> 
  if (tiers[data.id]) data.tier = tiers[data.id]
  [orderId, data]
}

println "orders after adding tiers"
println "orders: $orders"
```

which produces the same output as the initial code.

Comment: Thank you @Matias Bjarland! I am getting error message - No such property: id for class: java.lang.Object. I am guessing it is due to the fact that I am getting data in curly braces versus your example in square brackets... Wondering if there is a way to switch the brackets, execute the code and switch it back...

Comment: Groovy uses square brackets to define list and map literals. That is part of the language. You could always parse the input as json (assuming it is json) which would give you the appropriate map structure in groovy.

Comment: added code snippet parsing json. Should be noted that your initial data was broken (missing colon characters, misplaced quotation chars etc).